# Button Not Showing Up In Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

despite addressing other similar questions I don't quite understand why these buttons won't appear in my layout screen, could someone please explain why?

The textview shows up fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lab1.ac01220.com1032_lab.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_string"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your UI screenshot

Comment: Also, please post the Java code for the activity or fragment

Comment: Your `TextView` is taking up all of the space. Try changing it's height and width to `wrap_content` and see what happens

Comment: turn the device "horizontal" LOL I like this post. Don't feel bad we all do this kind of thing from time to time

Comment: @codeMagic absolutely magical, make an answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TextView` is taking up all of the space do to the height and width being `match_parent`. And since `LinearLayouts` are laid out in sequential order there's no space for anything that comes after it.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Change that to `wrap_content`, use `layout_weight`, or a specific dimension (whatever suits your needs).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix. Turn the device "horizontal" and you can see the button.

Answer (score 0):

you can still set the `TextView` to `match_parent`. But remember to set a `margin` and `layout weight`.

Take a look at my snippet below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```